# Soft thresholding in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have an array with `1024` elements and I have a threshold `t>0` to do the following operations

```
A[i] = A[i] - t  // if  A[i] > t
A[i] = A[i] + t  // if A[i] < -t
A[i] = 0         // otherwise
```

So, I have written a simple Kernel:

```
void __global__  Kernel_Shrinkage(float* A, float t, int n){
    int i = blockIdx*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    while( i < n)
    { 
        float temp = A[i];
        if (fabs(temp) > t)
        {
            if (temp < 0)
            {
                A[i] += t;
            } 
            else
                A[i] -= t;
        } 
        else
            A[i] = 0;
        id += gridDim.x * blockDim.x;}}
```

It shows 6x speed up as compared with a CPU implementation. Because this kernel has many control statements, I suspect there is a way to optimize this kernel. Any help?

And if I have the prerequisite that the array is sparse which means that the most elements in it are `0`?

Comment: You have various typographical errors in your kernel code.  It will not compile.

Comment: If the array is sparse, then you can choose to store only the non-zero elements of `A` and their indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is an implementation of the **soft thresholding problem** since it is computing:

[image]

This problem has been already faced in: [Soft Thresholding CUDA implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765197/soft-thresholding-cuda-implementation), where two solutions have been devised.

By the code below, I'm comparing the two mentioned solution and the solution provided by Robert Crovella.

**CODE** (CUDA error check neglected, for the sake of brevity, but ALWAYS add it)

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time */

#define BLOCKSIZE 256

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/*****************/
/* TEST KERNEL 1 */
/*****************/
__global__ void myKernel1(float* __restrict__ x, float lambda, const int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N) {
        float xa = fabs(x[tid]); 
        x[tid] = (xa > lambda) ? x[tid] * ((xa - lambda) / xa) : 0;
    }

}    

/*****************/
/* TEST KERNEL 2 */
/*****************/
__global__ void myKernel2(float* __restrict__ x, float lambda, const int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N) {
        float xa = fabs(x[tid]); 
        x[tid] = signbit(lambda-xa)*copysign(xa-lambda,x[tid]);
    }

}

/*****************/
/* TEST KERNEL 3 */
/*****************/
__global__ void myKernel3(float* __restrict__ x, float lambda, const int N)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N) {
        float temp = x[tid];
        if (temp > lambda)
            temp -= lambda;
        else if (-temp > lambda)
            temp += lambda;
        else 
            temp = 0;
        x[tid] = temp;    }

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main() {

    const int N = 10000000;

    const float lambda = 0.3f;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_data(N);
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_data[i] = rand()/RAND_MAX - 0.5f;

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_data(h_data);

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    myKernel1<<<iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE),BLOCKSIZE>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), lambda, N);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time kernel 1:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    d_data = h_data;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    myKernel2<<<iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE),BLOCKSIZE>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), lambda, N);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time kernel 2:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

    d_data = h_data;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    myKernel3<<<iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE),BLOCKSIZE>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data()), lambda, N);

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time kernel 3:  %3.3f ms \n", time);

}
```

**COMPUTATIONAL RESULTS** (Tested with CUDA 6.0)

*GT540M*

```
Kernel 1    47.9ms
Kernel 2    41.5ms
Kernel 3    42.4ms
```

*K20c*

```
Kernel 1    0.676ms
Kernel 2    0.591ms
Kernel 3    0.592ms
```

Comment: Suggestsions: 1. You should re-copy the data to the device before each kernel call.  Otherwise subsequent kernel calls are operating on thresholded data.  2. Also, I would suggest not creating an event that has already been created, although I don't know that it is illegal.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for pointing my mistakes out. I have improved the answer according to your suggestions. In particular, I have removed the two new creations of the already created events and also copied the data before the two subsequent kernel calls. It seems still that your solution is the fastest :-)

Comment: Your posted `printf` formatting does not match between the 3 output lines.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thanks, I have fixed the problem (my mistake in updating the version of the code in the browser), but the results I reported were already obtained for the correct `printf` formatting.

Comment: Something is strange.  I have run your program with a few minor changes for linux compatibility both on a K20m and a Quadro5000 using CUDA 6.0, and I see almost no difference in execution time between kernel 2 and 3.  For example my K20m results are: `kernel 1: 0.671 ms, kernel 2: 0.586 ms, kernel 3: 0.585 ms`

Comment: @RobertCrovella Sorry, my fault. I have fixed the misprints.

Answer (score 1):

This might be quicker:

```
__global__ void Kernel_Shrinkage(float* A, float t, int n){
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    while( i < n)
    { 
      float temp = A[i];
      if (temp > t)
        temp -= t;
      else if (-temp > t)
        temp += t;
      else 
        temp = 0;
      A[i] = temp;
    i += gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    }
}
```

Before assuming warp divergence with such simple code, I would check to see what kind of job the compiler is doing with predicating instructions.  There may be no warp divergence at all.  You can do this either by inspecting the code directly (`cuobjdump -sass ...`) or with a profiler.

The implication in your code is that `t>=0` always:

```
    if (fabs(temp) > t)
```

My code makes the same assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (temp < 0)
            {
                A[i] += t;
            } 
            else
                A[i] -= t;
```

equals

```
A[i]-=-signbitof(temp)*t; // no branching
```

signbitof() 's implementation is another question

Also doing same thing for 'fabs(temp) > t' yields something like:

```
A[i]-=-signbitof(temp)*t*pseudofabsgreaterthan(temp,t); // zero divergence
```